# What is an inlay apartment?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, translation, german

I am not sure if this word really exists. I am trying to translate the German word *Einliegerwohnung* into English.

I live in the ground floor of a house and the owner lives in the upper floor. So what do I call for the kind of apartment I stay. Is it an *inlay apartment*?

Google doesn't have any good results for *inlay apartment*. If the apartment I live in is not an *inlay apartment*, what can I call it?

Comment: Is it a duplex ( http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duplex+apartment) or just two separate apartments?

Comment: its a 2 storeyed home.

Comment: In British English, it's a [**flat**.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flat)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean "a ground floor flat (UK)"  or "a first floor apartment (US)"?  ***Note that UK English and US English name floors differently. Therefore you need to specify which version of English you are using.***

Comment: @chaslyfromUK the floor that I am living doesnt  have any significance. I am living in one floor of a home. So what can i say about the place i am living?

Comment: I think the word i am looking for is something similar to granny flat.

Comment: Who is grammy?  The person the family calls grandmother/father?  You aren't explaining this very clearly.

Comment: it was a typo. Granny flat

Comment: A granny flat, is a purely British term (as far as I am aware). It usually refers to an extension that is built onto the outside of an existing home to provide a degree of independence for an elderly relative.

Comment: I too read about granny flat. But I don't think that fits best into the situation that I am having

Comment: There is "owner-occupied apartment", where the owner occupies one of the units of a multi-unit building.  Or "granny flat" is a reasonably well-recognized term in the US.

Comment: Are you asking about the specific case of a *house* (single dwelling) that has been *divided* into apartments?

Comment: Yes. The one that has been mentioned in the question.

Comment: The german word is Einliegerwohnung.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what an inlay apartment is but I think you live in **a paired-home** or a **duplex apartment**.

> [A paired home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_home) is two homes that share a wall and have opposite side entry.

or

> **duplex apartment / a two-storey flat**
>
> [Two-storey flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apartment#Two-storey_flat)
>
> an existing small house or cottage that has been lifted up to
>   accommodate the creation of a new basement floor housing a separate
>   apartment, then set down again; thus becoming a modest two-story flat.

Comment: a duplex apartment could be  a good term. But nowhere it mentions that I am not having the full house to live but only one storey of the apartment to live.

Answer (score 1):

It only just occurred to me now, weeks later, that *inlay apartment* is almost certainly a typographical error for ***[in-law apartment](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-law-apartment)***. The answer can stand.

---

I did a web search on floor plans for *Einliegerwohnung*, and based on that I think I can provide an answer.

[image: winkelbungalow mit Einliegerwohnung]

The above seems to be typical; in other plans, the main unit and the secondary unit may share an entrance vestibule or foyer, but generally the living spaces are self-contained, and they do not fall under other categories:

- They do not share living spaces like a kitchen or toilet, and cannot be accessed internally from one another, so it is an apartment or flat as opposed to a *guest suite*.
- They are not equivalent, so they are not simply two halves of a *duplex* or *paired home*.
- The secondary unit is purpose-built as such, so it is not simply a large house that has been subdivided into separately rented areas as a multiple-unit dwelling.
- They are attached, so the smaller unit is not a *guest house* (in the sense of *[A small, separate house on the grounds of a larger one, used for accommodating guests](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/guest-house)*, ODO) or *[laneway house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laneway_house)*.

The smaller or secondary unit may be known as a ***[granny flat](http://www.domain.com.au/news/why-i-love-living-in-a-granny-flat-20150902-gjdgla/)***, an ***[in-law apartment](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/inlaw-apartment-45307.html)***, or an ***[accessory apartment](http://urbanland.uli.org/planning-design/rethinking-private-accessory-dwellings/)*** among **[many, many other terms](http://accessorydwellings.org/2012/06/04/beware-of-the-many-synonyms-for-adus/)** which vary slightly in usage depending on the locale. Such terms reflect a typical kind of resident— one who does not want or cannot afford a main residence, but can make use of a smaller one.

A common industry term appears to be *[accessory dwelling unit](http://urbanland.uli.org/planning-design/rethinking-private-accessory-dwellings/)* (ADU). Wikipedia uses the term *[secondary suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_suite)*, though in the U.S. there is a regulatory distinction between an accessory unit and a secondary unit.

But in my experience with both landlords and tenants of such units, I would say ***there is no special term*** in common usage. No one advertises an "accessory dwelling unit for rent" on Craigslist, or says they're looking to lease an ADU for graduate school. The space is simply a *flat* or an *apartment* or a *suite*. It may be described by its location— *[basement flat](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/the-advantages-of-life-below-stairs-1199463.html)*, *[carriage house apartment](https://www.thegarageplanshop.com/garage-apartment-plans/garage-plans/7/1.php)*, etc., or as *an apartment attached to someone's house*— but it will otherwise be understood from context whether the apartment being rented out is on the same property as the owner's living space or not.